# getRows below the model length

Tags: sapui5

I have a table with a visible row count of 10 (this is fix). And the table has a binding with a total of 62 in length. When calling `.getRows()`, I only get the 10 rows visible but I need to get also the other rows (rows 11 onwards). I need to update the specific row/cell with CSS. How can I get the object in that cell, which is a button, and update its CSS?

Or is there any way that I can only apply the CSS with the specific row? For example, row 1 col 1 only and when I scroll the table, it will be removed or the CSS will not apply with the other?

#### Sample image

[image: sample image]

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are building the table?

Comment: in view i have bind the table
<t:Table selectionMode="None" id="idEntryTable"
      rows="{path: 'ScenarioModelEntry>/entryParamTable'}" visibleRowCount="10"
      enableColumnReordering="false" columnFreeze="false" firstVisibleRowChanged="onScrollTable">

then in a controller i have set a model name ScenarioModelEntry.

Comment: What is the condition for that specific cell in order to apply the custom CSS? If the "Webname" equals "Kienbaum" for example?